# Brownian motion limit of random walk

Tags: probability

Let $X_n(t)= \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{n}} \left(\sum_{k=1}^{[nt]} U_k +(nt - [nt])U_{[nt]+1} \right)$
with $ (U_n, n \geq 1)$  iid .

1. $X_n$ is a processus ? Yes cause $X_n(t)$ is measurable $\forall t$ (finite sum of measurable variable)
2. Let defne $X$: $X(t)=\lim_n(X_n(t))$. Does $X$ is a processus? (ie) Does $X_n(t) $ is measurable ($\forall t$)? (We have a theorem for a.e. limit of measurable functin ...). So yes!
3. Let consider the second term of the sum.
   [image]
   So $X(t)$ follow a gauss law
4. Does  $X_n$ is a processus independant ?  I think no, because of the second terme of the sum.But at the limit this term disapear with n. Is there a theorem wich specify this ?

-

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $(U_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is centered and the variance of $U_1$ is $\sigma$. The limiting distribution of $X(t)$ is indeed Gaussian. However, the sequence $(X_n(1))_{n\geqslant 1}$ is not independent. Otherwise, we would deduce that $U_1+U_2$ is independent of $U_1$ and this would imply that the distribution of $U_1$ is degenerated.